# RETURN trap in Bash not executing for function

Tags: bash, function, trap

I'm dabbling in traps in Bash again. I've just noticed the RETURN trap doesn't fire up for functions.

```
$ trap 'echo ok' RETURN
$ f () { echo ko; }
$ f
ko
$ . x
ok
$ cat x
$
```

As you can see it goes off as expected for sourcing the empty file `x`.

Bash's `man` has it so:

> If a sigspec is RETURN, the command arg is executed each time a shell
>   function or a script executed with the . or source builtins finishes
>   executing.

What am I missing then?

I have GNU bash, version 4.4.12(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu).

Comment: The trap only fires if function is executed in `.` or `source` context. In your example, it works as expected. Calling `f` alone not trigger the trap.

Comment: @cuonglm So if `x` contains `f` then the trap should fire up twice?

Comment: No, only once. The trap fire up after each `.` or `source`

Comment: @cuonglm What makes you think so? Is the documentation not up to date?

Comment: That's what I understand when reading the doc. Each time `.` or `source` finish executing, if trap `RETURN` is installed, it will be executed.

Comment: What about `the command arg is executed each time a shell function`?

Comment: It must execute with `.` or `source`.

Comment: @cuonglm Why would function be mentioned here? Function can't be sourced on its own.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As I understand this, there's an exception to the doc snippet in my question. The snippet was:

> If a sigspec is RETURN, the command arg is executed each time a shell
>   function or a script executed with the . or source builtins finishes
>   executing.

The exception is described here:

> All other aspects of the shell execution environment are identical
>   between a function and its caller with these exceptions: **the DEBUG and
>   RETURN traps** (see the description of the trap builtin  under SHELL 
>   BUILTIN  COMMANDS  below) **are not inherited unless the function has
>   been given the trace attribute (see the description of the declare
>   builtin below) or the -o functrace shell option has been enabled with
>   the set builtin** (in which case all functions inherit the DEBUG and
>   RETURN traps), and the ERR trap is not inherited unless the -o
>   errtrace shell option has been enabled.

As for `functrace`, it can be turned on with the `typeset`'s `-t`:

> -t     Give each name the trace attribute.  Traced functions inherit the DEBUG and RETURN traps from the calling shell.  The trace
>   attribute has no special meaning for variables.

Also `set -o functrace` does the trick.

Here's an illustration.

```
$ trap 'echo ko' RETURN
$ f () { echo ok; }
$ cat y
f
$ . y
ok
ko
$ set -o functrace
$ . y
ok
ko
ko
```

As for `declare`, it's the `-t` option again:

> -t     Give each name the trace attribute.  Traced functions inherit the DEBUG and RETURN traps from the calling shell.  The trace
>   attribute has no special meaning for variables.

Also `extdebug` enables function tracing, as in [ikkachu's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/419037/181255).

Answer (score 2):

On Bash 4.4., it only seems to work for functions if `extdebug` is enabled, though I can't see that mentioned in the documentation.

```
$ cat ret.sh 
trap "echo ret" RETURN
foo() { echo "$1"; }
foo "without extdebug"
shopt -s extdebug
foo "with extdebug"

$ bash ret.sh
without extdebug
with extdebug
ret

$ bash --version |head -1
GNU bash, version 4.4.12(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
```

In Bash 4.3, it doesn't seem to work for functions at all.

Comment: `extdebug`'s description has it. `5.     Function tracing is enabled: command substitution, shell functions, and subshells invoked with ( command ) inherit the DEBUG and RETURN traps.`

Comment: And it's not only with `extdebug`. See my answer https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/419045/181255

Comment: @tomasz, bah, I looked at extdebug, but didn't see it. I'm a bit amused the requirements aren't mentioned under `trap`.

Comment: @ikkachu I often have an impression Bash's man is a can of spam.